# JDialog windowClosed event called when owner JFrame close

Tags: java, swing

I have the test code below. 
After opening the dialog when I close the it the windowClosed method is called, but it's called again when I close the JFrame and the dialog was just closed, why?  I am not closing the dialog in this case.
So I see:

```
closed
closed
```

How can I prevent it?

I don't want to set EXIT_ON_CLOSE on JFrame (this will not call the windowClosed again) because this terminate the application and in the real case I can't do this.

Thanks for the help

```
public final class Test4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Runnable runnable = new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run() {

                final JFrame frame = new JFrame("test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setSize(300, 300);
                JButton btn = new JButton("test");
                frame.add(btn);
                frame.setVisible(true);
                btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

                        openDialog(frame);
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(runnable);
    }

    private static void openDialog(Frame owner) {

        JDialog testDialog = new JDialog(owner);
        testDialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        testDialog.setSize(100,100);
        testDialog.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {

                System.out.println("closed");
            }
        });
        testDialog.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you saying you don't want the `JDialog` to close when you close the owner `JFrame`? I tried running your example program and the behavior doesn't seem unusual to me.

Comment: The steps to see what I mean: I open the dialog using the button and close it, the windowClosed method is called; then I close the JFrame and again the windowClosed method is called (the dialog it was closed before). I want to prevent the windowClosed call at the JFrame closed event keeping the dialog a child of the frame. Hope is more clear.

Comment: Although it may work (at this point) your dialog is asked to open against a AWT Frame component whereas your actual frame is created as a SWING component. Change: `private static void openDialog(Frame owner) {...}` to: `private static void openDialog(JFrame owner) {...}`.

Comment: @DevilsHnd It's the same in my test. The "closed" message is shown 2 times

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce that then, with the given example code. I'm on OSX El Capitan with Java 8. @DevilsHnd That won't make any difference. If you look at the [`JDialog` constructors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html), `Frame` is already the most-specific overload.

Comment: True @Radiodef but it is good practice not to mix the two.  I also can not reproduce the problem when running your provided code unless two dialogs are opened (Windows10 - NetBeans - Java 8) which is allowable in your code.

Comment: Tested it on java 8 and, as you said it works with it, so it was a bug resolved. Sorry but I am not using java 8 in the real case.  I will close the question or if @Radiodef want to answer I give him the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From comments and tests probably it was a bug resolved in java 8 because with java 8 It works fine.